# How does 'case' statement work in a function?

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

I have the following ruby code:

```
def xyz(n)
  case n
  when 0
    0
  when 1
    1
  else
    xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
  end
end

puts xyz(ARGF.gets.to_i)
```

I executed the code as:

```
Ruby$ echo "4" | ruby test.rb
```

I want to know how the answer becomes `3`. I don't understand the:

```
xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
```

part of the code. Please explain.

Comment: That is called as recursion. It's when a function calls itself directly or indirectly to gather the final result. Read more about it here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/ or in computer science channel of stackexchange

Comment: It means that `xyz(4)` is calculated via `xyz(3) + xyz(2)`.

Comment: Your question is unclear: in your title, you ask how a case statement (which doesn't actually exist in Ruby, Ruby only has case expressions and no case statements) works in a function (which Ruby doesn't have, Ruby only has methods, blocks, lambdas and procs, but no functions). Then in the body, you ask how a specific method call works. Can you clarify what it is you are interested in?

Comment: additionally many rubyists would consider a case expression (especially this one) code smell. Instead a guard clause would be sufficient such that `def xyz(n); return n unless n > 1; xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2); end;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `recursive` function, calling a funciton by `itself`

Here are the different `steps of the function execution` and the `output` from each step:

**Step 1:**

```
def xyz(n)
    n = 4.
    case n
    when 0
        0
    when 1
        1
    else
        n = 4, so it comes here and calls
        xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
        xyz(3) + xyz(2) // no result
    end
end
```

**No o/p as both conditions make recursive call**

---

**Step 2:**

```
def xyz(n)
    n = 3.
    case n
    when 0
        0
    when 1
        1
    else
        n = 3, so it comes here and calls
        xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
        xyz(2) + xyz(1) // recursion stops here as case 1 is 1 // so o/p is 1 for hjere
    end
end
```

**o/p is one as xyz(1) will execute to 1.
Current O/p: 1
Overall O/p: 1**

---

**Step 3:**

```
def xyz(n)
    n = 2.
    case n
    when 0
        0
    when 1
        1
    else
        n = 2, so it comes here and calls
        xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
        xyz(1) + xyz(0) // 1
    end
end
```

**Here o/p is  1 again since `xyz(1)` will execute to `1`, 
Current O/p: 1
Overall O/p: 1 + 1 ==> 2**

---

**Step 4:**

```
def xyz(n)
    n = 2.
    case n
    when 0
        0
    when 1
        1 // 1
    else
        n = 1, I wont come here
        xyz(n - 1) + xyz(n - 2)
    end
end
```

**Here o/p is  1 again since `case 1` will execute to `1`, 
Current O/p: 1
Overall O/p: 1 + 1 + 1 ==> 3**

---

**So,the final output is `3`**

Comment: Appreciate ... well understood